# possible ?: mysql row to an if condition

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement

hi guys im trying to insert a mysql data to a variable that will set an if condition depending on the result. is this possible, am i doing it right? what is the right way to do it ? what i want to achieve is to validate if there's a equal value given by the user inside my mysql rows.

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','test','');

if (!$db)
{
  print "<h1>Unable to Connect to MySQL</h1>";
}

$dbname = 'test';

$btest = mysql_select_db($dbname);

if (!$btest)
{
  print "<h1>Unable to Select the Database</h1>";
}


$sql_statement  = "SELECT * ";
$sql_statement .= "FROM registered_email ";


$result = mysql_query($sql_statement);

$outputDisplay = "";
$myrowcount = 0;

if (!$result) {
  $outputDisplay .= "<br /><font color=red>MySQL No: ".mysql_errno();
  $outputDisplay .= "<br />MySQL Error: ".mysql_error();
  $outputDisplay .= "<br />SQL Statement: ".$sql_statement;
  $outputDisplay .= "<br />MySQL Affected Rows: ".mysql_affected_rows()."</font><br />";
} 
 else{
  $numresults = mysql_num_rows($result);

  for ($i = 0; $i < $numresults; $i++)
  {



    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $id  = $row['id'];
    $sentEmailClients = $row['email'];

    $outputDisplay.= "".$sentEmailClients."<br />";
  }

 }
```

and here what im trying to achieve, btw is $clientEmail has a default values so dont worry about that.

```
if($clientEmail === $outputDisplay){

 ...... some codes..........
}
else{
....... some codes.......
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. You want an if-statement, and you gave us an if-statement? And where does `?:` come in? Please be more specific.

Comment: well my if condition is not working but when i echo $outputDisplay i get all the data .. what i want is the $client to check each data to see if it has an equal value. i think my condition reads all the data in one variable.

Comment: You're appending the emails to the `$outputDisplay`-variable and adding `<br />` at the end, which means that `$outputDisplay` will never be equal to just one e-mail address, if that is what you're hoping.

Comment: well, im not really great at this, but what i thought is that if i put <br /> it can separate those data so that $clientEmail can check each and every data separately. ?

Comment: No. "<br />" is just a string. You are concatenating the same string, which will give you a string with something like: "email@example.com<br />email2@example.com<br />". `<br />` is just a line break in HTML.

Comment: yeah i thought so.. well what is the right way to do it. i tried in_array($outputDisplay); no luck

Comment: Btw... is all this code just to check if it already is registered? Then you should use a `WHERE ` in your SQL-query instead and just return a count on matches.

Answer (score 1):

you can use mysql row to compare with your user input. you can add condition, while you'r getting row value for the email inside the loop.

```
$email_exist = 0;//define the default value.
  for ($i = 0; $i < $numresults; $i++)
  {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $id  = $row['id'];
    $sentEmailClients = $row['email'];

    $outputDisplay.= "".$sentEmailClients."<br />";

    //my code start here
    if($sentEmailClients == $clientEmail) 
        $email_exist = 1;
  }
  //outside the loop
  if($email_exist == 1) {
   //..........write some code.......
  }else{
    //........write some code....... 
  }
```

Comment: are you getting any error? can you check, did you got the result set from the database?

Comment: But.. this will always set `$email_exists` as 0 unless the matching email is last, so this still won't work. You're overriding any previous value on each iteration.

Comment: ok, remove else from the loop and test it again.                                        else 
        $email_exist = 0;

Comment: This answer is better than mine, since he's only have a variable set to "0" or "1". (could be true/false but that's a minor detail). My answer can be very performance/memory heavy if you have a lot of email addresses and you don't need them for more than this check. (which still should be done in a SQL-query with a `WHERE`, if this code only is to check if an email exists in the database).

Comment: yes my plan is to check whether a mail exist, if it exist then it will not output a file. and if not it will appear.

Comment: i have a default insert query in this page. is it affecting my select query?

Comment: still not counting those emails

Comment: you can add multiple sql queries in one page. not an issue. use different variable and resource id to utilize its values.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a while loop?

**make sure to update to mysqli_* because mysql_* is deprecated and is going to get removed on php 7.0**

```
$email_exist = 0;//define the default value.
  while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) // you are using associative array and not the indexed once tho you should go for mysql_fetch_assoc
  {

    $id  = $row['id'];
    $sentEmailClients = $row['email'];

    $outputDisplay.= "".$sentEmailClients."<br />";

    //my code start here
    if($sentEmailClients == $clientEmail) 
        $email_exist += 1; //maybe it exist more than once?
  }
  //outside the loop
  if($email_exist == 1) {
   //..........write some code.......
  }else{
    //........write some code....... 
  }
```

or you can do something more simple like this

```
$query = "select email from tablename where email='$clientemail'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count > 0) {
// email exists
} else {
// doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: `$outputDisplay.= "".$sentEmailClients."<br />";`
outputDisplay won't be equal to client mail because it contains <br /> tag already 
the second example should be working fine there was a mistyping sorry i edited it